# Need to convert json values to variables from cookie

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I am sending a cookie with certain values and in the receiving page i need to extract only a single value from it, where i need help -

sending page -

```
$customer_email='john@gmail.com';
$time =time();
$user_details = array($customer_email,$time);
setcookie('users' , json_encode($user_details) , $time+3000, '/');
```

receiving page -

```
$cval = array();
$cval = $_COOKIE['users'];
```

now, output is -

```
["john@gmail.com",1419929200]
```

I am not able to convert this to object using **get_object_vars**. I just need to pick each elements in variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are `var_dump($cval);` You will see this is a string, not an object:

```
string '["john@gmail.com",1419933343]' (length=29)
```

So you need to `json_decode($_COOKIE['users']);`. But, in this case, you will get back an array, not an object, so you can not use the `get_object_vars` on this.

```
array
  0 => string 'john@gmail.com' (length=14)
  1 => int 1419933343
```

Comment: ya, took your json_decode comment, got what i wanted. thank you. +1

Comment: hey @lolka_bolka ,do u have any idea of how to get the values of an associative array from the cookie? my returned value is string and once i convert to array,i have - [{"id":"7","quantity":"3","price":1500,"title":"shirt"},{"id":"9","quantity":"4","price":1290,"title":"shoe"}]